# How do I add certain elements from a column to another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I started out with the dataframe below

```
    0
0   Alabama[edit]
1   Auburn (Auburn University)[1]
2   Florence (University of North Alabama)
3   Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]
4   Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]
```

Then I cleaned it up to this

```
         State        RegionName
0        Alabama    
1        Auburn 
2        Florence   
3        Jacksonville   
4        Livingston
```

I am not sure how to move Auburn, Florence, Jacksonville and Livingston to RegionName as they are regions in Alabama.
Also I need to apply the moving of regions(500+) to their respective states(50 states) for the rest of my data.

Below is how the data is mapped(I added in the type of each row on the side)

```
State-->Alaska  
Region->Fairbanks   
State-->Arizona 
Region->Flagstaff   
Region->Tempe   
Region->Tucson
```

Expected answer:

```
    State     RegionName
0  Alabama     Auburn
1  Alabama     Florence
2  Alabama     Jacksonville
3  Alabama     Livingston
```

Comment: how do you know which region is part of what state? Can you infer that from the data, somehow?

Comment: do you have mapping of states and repective regions. if  yes, can you give some sample data.

Comment: The data is added by state then all its respective regions going down the column. I could create a dictionary manually but there are about 567 rows in total.

Comment: I have added in an extra table on how the data is mapped.

Comment: Thanks. What data structure contains the mapping? Is it a dict? Another dataframe? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do, starting with original data:

```
df['State'] = df[0].str.extract('(.*)\[edit\]').ffill()

df['RegionName'] = df[0].str.extract('(.*) \(')

df = df.dropna(subset=['RegionName'])
```

Output:

```
                                                 0    State    RegionName
1                    Auburn (Auburn University)[1]  Alabama        Auburn
2           Florence (University of North Alabama)  Alabama      Florence
3  Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]  Alabama  Jacksonville
4       Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]  Alabama    Livingston
```

Comment: Only problem is that there are other states below with their respective regions as well.

Comment: This is a very common data set extracted from wikipedia. That said, the provided code should work.

Comment: Thank you for the help